# Mensagem de erro "wntdll.pdb not loaded" ao criar um destrutor virtual

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Eu estava tentando criar um destrutor virtual para uma classe, contudo, ao tentar compilar o código abaixo, no modo 'Debug', o Visual Studio 2017 interrompeu a execução do programa,  informou que uma exceção foi lançada e mostrou a mensagem de erro "wntdll.pdb not loaded".

Tentei no modo 'Release', a exceção não é lançada, mas o programa é encerrado prematuramente no mesmo ponto.

Abaixo o código do programa:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
protected:  
        int* m_data;    
public:
    Base(int data) {
        std::cout << "Base Constructor.\n";
        m_data = new int(data);
    }
    ~Base() {
        std::cout << "Base Destructor.\n";
        delete m_data;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
protected:
    double* m_moreData;
public:
    Derived(int data, double moreData) : Base(data) {
        std::cout << "Derived Constructor.\n";
        m_moreData = new double(moreData);
    }
    virtual ~Derived() {
        std::cout << "Derived Destructor.\n";
        delete m_moreData;
    }
};

int main() {

    Base* b = new Derived(10, 25.0);
    delete b;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

A saída do programa, tanto no modo 'Debug' como 'Release' é:

```
Base Constructor.
Derived Constructor.
Base Destructor.
```

E no modo 'Debug' quando eu clico no botão continuar, o Visual Studio informa que a exceção foi lançada na linha `delete b;`.

Como eu faço para corrigir isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esquece a pergunta. Cometi um erro bobo. Declarei o destrutor da classe derivada como virtual, quando o correto era o destrutor da classe base:

```
class Base {
protected:  
        int* m_data;    
public:
    Base(int data) {
        std::cout << "Base Constructor.\n";
        m_data = new int(data);
    }
    virtual ~Base() {
        std::cout << "Base Destructor.\n";
        delete m_data;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
protected:
    double* m_moreData;
public:
    Derived(int data, double moreData) : Base(data) {
        std::cout << "Derived Constructor.\n";
        m_moreData = new double(moreData);
    }
    ~Derived() {
        std::cout << "Derived Destructor.\n";
        delete m_moreData;
    }
};
```